# Load different Arrays into one UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uitableview

I have a `storyboard` based application and I would like to load a different `NSArray` into a single `UITableView`, but I don't know how to implement this into my app...

At the moment the structure of my app looks like this:

Tab Bar Controller --> Navigation Controller - ADD --> Add Auction View Controller (where is UITextfield to add auction name with Next button --> TableView Controller where I load `NSArray`.

Based on user choice from first `NSArray` - `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` application will load another `NSArray` with different data according to his choice, within the same `UITableViewController`.

Example of what I would like to achieve:

Selecting "Cars" will load `NSArray` with car list - selecting again "Car" Category will load up Car Brands `NSArray` and so on...

[EXAMPLE TABLEVIEW FLOW](http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8201/8214481162_119ea066b4_c.jpg)

I would like to store user choice from `NSArray` and after going though all the steps display all the selected choices in new `UITableView Controller`.

So far I managed to create application that allows to set the Auction name and load first `NSArray`.
I need help to make the next step and load new `NSArray` based on user choice in the same `UITableView Controller`

My files:

**SelectClassTableViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SelectClassTableViewController : UITableViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDataSource>

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *Classes;

@end
```

**SelectClassTableViewController.h**

```
#import "SelectClassTableViewController.h"

@interface SelectClassTableViewController ()
{
    NSArray *ClassesArray;
}

@end

@implementation SelectClassTableViewController

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    ClassesArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Cars", @"Motorcycles", @"Boats", @"Planes", @"Other", nil];
    self.Classes.delegate = self;
    self.Classes.dataSource = self;

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Number of sections in TableView
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return ClassesArray.count;
}

// Set name of grouped table view
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return @"Select Car Type:";
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ClassesCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Sets 
    cell.textLabel.text = [ClassesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}

#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.
    /*
     <#DetailViewController#> *detailViewController = [[<#DetailViewController#> alloc] initWithNibName:@"<#Nib name#>" bundle:nil];
     // ...
     // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
     */
}

@end
```

.

I know that it is possible to do it using `UITableViewDataSource` but I don't know how to implement this protocol into my app. I'm still learning Objective-C, so any advice or help with my code would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: This arrangement is not the usual Apple way to do this. Normally, when you select a row in a table, you push to a new view controller that shows the details based on your selection. Do you have a particular reason why you want to to it with one view controller?

Comment: I tried to avoid ending up with +13 separate view controllers just to load different arrays during "pick from list" steps to create a new auction. 

If that is the right approach could you please advice how to do it using view controllers ?

Should I assign user choice to variable and pass it to another viewcontroller, and so on... in the end display all the variables in one viewcontroller ?

Answer (score 0):

Create a NSString in the header file. In viewDidLoad, set the NSString to `@"Main"`. In `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, set the NSString to whatever array you want to show (array 1, array 2, array 3...), and reload the table.

In `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, detect which array is the focus by checking the value of the NSString using an if statement.

```
if ([string isEqualToString: @"Main"]) {

    //show main array

} else if ([string isEqualToString: @"Cars"]) {

    //show cars array...

}
```